# Turnstile page animation for first xaml page of application is not happening on application load

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

I am creating a Windows Phone application and i used turnstile animation on all the pages in my application.

The turnstile animation is happening in navigating in and out, but it does not happen when the app is loaded and first page is displayed. The page contains a panorama control with three panorama items.

When the app starts, after splash screen, the page just appear. no turnstile or any other animation happens

Kindly help with this issue.
Any help will be highly appreciated
Thanx for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The whole app should be opened with animation. If you have the animation turned on properly on the first page, it will come animated, but not the page - the animated item will be the splashscreen.

When you close the app, it will also be animated.